# Installing the CPAN Module Crypt-SSLeay-0.57

Tags: ubuntu, cpan

```
Using the Command Makefile.PL tyied to install but i am getting the below information how can fix this?

 No installed SSL libraries found in any of the following places.
/local
/local/ssl
/opt/ssl
/usr
/usr/local
/usr/local/ssl
/usr/local/openssl
```

You will have to either specify a directory location at the following prompt, or rerun the Makefile.PL program and use the --lib switch to specify the path. If the path in question is considered standard on your platform, please consider filing a bug report in order to
have it taken into account in a subsequent version of Crypt::SSLeay.

This host looks like it is running Debian. Crypt::SSLeay needs to be compiled with C headers that the libssl-dev package makes available. Please install that package before trying to build this module. (You can always deinstall the package afterwards, once
Crypt::SSLeay has been built).
Which SSL install path do you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

Install the missing package (which is mentioned in the error message):

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

(I wonder if Crypt-SSLeay should get even user-friendlier and output this command line in the error message, so the user just needs to copy'n'paste?)